# Set date report parameter default expr to previous work day

Tags: jasper-reports

Please advice how to set report parameter of type Date default expression to previous work day. Tried WORKDAY function but it returns next work day, and I need one in the past I don't need to take in account local holidays, all I need to have parameter set to date that is closest work day in the past. Week starts from Monday.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the below expression

```
WORKDAY(new Date((TODAY().getTime())-24*60*60*1000),0)
```

Hope this should solve your problem

Comment: Thank you, I've tested your solution, but unfortunately iy shows just previous day, on Monday it points to Sunday...

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it via following expression:

```
new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(Integer.parseInt("2"),Integer.parseInt("3"),Integer.parseInt("4"),Integer.parseInt("5"),Integer.parseInt("6"))).contains(WEEKDAY(new Date(),false))?(TODAY( )-1):(WEEKDAY(new Date(),false)==7?(TODAY( )-2):(TODAY( )-3))
```